# How to return all objects associated with a user that are all in another table too with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

I'm doing a electric-scooter project (school project) like LIME and I need to return the result of a certain query (see below)

I'm using MYSQL 5.7.24, and I have already try a hundred of queries with no good matching result.
I have 2 tables for this query: 
Trips Table that contains userID, scooterID and other rows.
Reload Table that contains userID, scooterID and other rows.

My query is supposed to return the list of users that have used all the scooters they have loaded.

The actual problem is "that have used ALL the scooters...".

Here is an example of not working query:

```
SELECT r.userID
FROM reload r
LEFT JOIN trips v
ON r.useID= v.`userID` AND r.scooterID= v.scooterID WHERE r.`scooterID ` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY r.userID
```

Example:

If user X use scooter A,B and reload scooter A,B. My query is supposed to return the userID of user X.

Now, if user X use scooter A,B and reload scooter A,B,C. My query is supposed to NOT return the userID of user X.

Comment: I am having difficulty with your terminology what does ' they have recharged.' mean and what does 'reload scooter' mean?

Comment: Let's hope an edit can go some way to resolving Salmon's difficulties https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm sorry, recharged and reload means loaded. is it understandable now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a `WHERE` clause you need a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT r.userID
FROM reload r LEFT JOIN trips v
ON r.userID= v.userID AND r.scooterID = v.scooterID 
GROUP BY r.userID
HAVING SUM(v.scooterID IS NULL) = 0
```

If there are `null` values in column `v.scooterID` for a `userID`, then the condition `v.scooterID IS NULL` will evaluate to `1` and this user will be excluded from the results.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bfUQcKmS6WZNch5JRiLwWT/0).